# AsyncTask - missing something

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I'm doing some project and I'm stuck ... I'm doing something wrong, probably with AsyncTask and I have no idea what to fix and how .... there is code I have right now.

ReviewData.class

```
public class ReviewData implements Parcelable {

private String mAuthor, mContent;

public ReviewData(String author, String content) {
    this.mAuthor = author;
    this.mContent = content;
}

private ReviewData(Parcel in) {
    mAuthor = in.readString();
    mContent = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ReviewData> CREATOR = new Creator<ReviewData>() {
    @Override
    public ReviewData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ReviewData(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ReviewData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ReviewData[size];
    }
};

//Getter method for review author
public String getAuthor() {
    return mAuthor;
}

//Setter method for review author
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.mAuthor = author;
}

//Getter method for review content
public String getContent() {
    return mContent;
}

//Setter method for review content
public void setContent(String content) {
    this.mContent = content;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mAuthor);
    dest.writeString(mContent);
}
```

}

ReviewAdapter.class

```
public class ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReviewAdapter.ReviewViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<ReviewData> mReviewList;
private Context mContext;

public ReviewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ReviewData> reviewList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mReviewList = reviewList;
}

@Override
public ReviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    mContext = parent.getContext();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.review_item_list,
            parent, false);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    return new ReviewViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ReviewViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(mReviewList != null) {
        ReviewData reviewData = mReviewList.get(position);
        holder.reviewAuthor.setText(reviewData.getAuthor());
        holder.reviewContent.setText(reviewData.getContent());
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mReviewList == null) {
        return  0;
    } else {
        return mReviewList.size();
    }
}

public void setReviewList(ArrayList<ReviewData> reviewList) {
    if(reviewList != null) {
        mReviewList = new ArrayList<>(reviewList);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ReviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView reviewAuthor;
    TextView reviewContent;

    public ReviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        reviewAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_author);
        reviewContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_content);
    }
}
```

}

NetworkUtils.class (but only code for Review url builder, for other thing works perfectly). PS. this parse is written as API documentation said ... it should be someurl/movie/{id}/reviews

```
//URL builder for reviews
public static URL buildReviewUrl(String id) {
    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_MOVIE_URL + id + REVIEW).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_API_KEY, API_KEY)
            .build();

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return url;
}
```

JsonData. class (also, only for Reviews, for other works perfectly...)

```
//JSON for Review
public static ArrayList<ReviewData> getReviewFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<ReviewData> listOfReviews = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject reviews = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray reviewsArray = reviews.getJSONArray(QUERY_RESULTS);
        for(int i = 0; i < reviewsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonReview = reviewsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String author = jsonReview.optString(REVIEW_AUTHOR);
            String content = jsonReview.optString(REVIEW_CONTENT);

            ReviewData reviewData = new ReviewData(author, content);

            listOfReviews.add(reviewData);
        }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ReviewJson", "JSON Review Error");
    }

    return listOfReviews;
}
```

ReviewAsyncTask.class

```
public class ReviewAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ReviewData>> {

private ReviewData mReviewData;

public interface ReviewResponse {
    void finished(ArrayList<ReviewData> output);
}

private ReviewResponse reviewResponse = null;

public ReviewAsyncTask(ReviewResponse reviewResponse) {
    this.reviewResponse = reviewResponse;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<ReviewData> doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String rawData = "";
    ArrayList<ReviewData> reviewList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        rawData = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpRequest(NetworkUtils
                .buildReviewUrl(String.valueOf(mReviewData)));
        reviewList = JsonData.getReviewFromJson(rawData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ReviewAsyncTask", "Error in ReviewAsyncTask");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("JSONAsync", "JSON problem");
    }

    return reviewList;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ReviewData> reviewData) {
    reviewResponse.finished(reviewData);

}
```

}

and MovieDetails activity (everything works fine except from the comment recycle review to next comment.

```
public class MovieDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements ReviewAsyncTask.ReviewResponse {

private final static String BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
private final static String SIZE = "w185/";

private ArrayList<ReviewData> mReviewList;

private ReviewAdapter mReviewAdapter;

@BindView(R.id.poster_detail)
ImageView mMoviePoster;
@BindView(R.id.title_detail)
TextView mMovieTitle;
@BindView(R.id.release_date)
TextView mReleaseDate;
@BindView(R.id.average_vote)
TextView mAverageVote;
@BindView(R.id.synopsis)
TextView mSynopsis;

@BindView(R.id.review_recycler)
RecyclerView mReviewRecycle;

Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    displayMovieDetail();

    //Review RecycleView
    mReviewList = new ArrayList<>();
    mReviewAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(this, mReviewList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mReviewRecycle.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mReviewRecycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mReviewRecycle.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);
}

@Override
public void finished(ArrayList<ReviewData> output) {
    ReviewAsyncTask reviewAsyncTask = new ReviewAsyncTask(this);
    reviewAsyncTask.execute();
}

/* Method for displaying the info about movies in activity details
 * @param mMoviePoster sets the movie poster
 * @param mMovieTitle sets original title of the movie
 * @param mReleaseDate sets release date of the movie
 * @param mAverageVote sets average rating grade of the movie
 * @param mSynopsis sets plot of the movie */
private void displayMovieDetail() {
    int idMovie = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(getString(R.string.movie_id));

    List<MovieData> movieList;
    movieList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(getString(R.string.movie_lsit));

    MovieData movieData = movieList.get(idMovie);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(BASE_URL + SIZE +
            movieData.getPoster()).into(mMoviePoster);
    mMovieTitle.setText(movieData.getTitle());
    mReleaseDate.setText(movieData.getReleaseDate());
    mAverageVote.setText(Double.toString(movieData.getRating()));
    mSynopsis.setText(movieData.getSynopsis());
}
```

}

P.S. I would share github link but I should give you my personal API key. :(

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @plaskoff reviews doesn't show up ...

Comment: Did you try checking the response? 
Are you getting the response?

Comment: @shb In logcat I'm getting this link  https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/null/reviews?api_key=myApiKey ... so this /null/ should me some id, that's why I'm getting nothing :(

Comment: Do you override onPostExecute() in the AsyncTask implementation?

Comment: @0X0nosugar no, U don't ... didn't even try ..

Comment: Then I think that's what is missing: doInBackground() returns an ArrayList which will be passed to onPostExecute(). Override it to add the data to your Adapter's data list.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'll try ... :)

Comment: @0X0nosugar I've edited AsyncTask in question ... I've added interface ReviewResponse with vodi method finished ... now I have to implement that interface in activity where I want to show reviews ... but it still shows null in the link

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you currently execute the AsyncTask

Comment: @0X0nosugar you can now take a look, I'm trying to figure out what to put in this method finished ... nothing works :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()` (like you did before) and in `finished()` you take the results and add them to the Adapter's data list. 
Finally, don't forget to call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);
    // skipping some lines of code here...
    mReviewRecycle.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);
    ReviewAsyncTask reviewAsyncTask = new ReviewAsyncTask(this);
    reviewAsyncTask.execute();
}

@Override
public void finished(ArrayList<ReviewData> output) {
    mReviewList.addAll(output);
    mReviewAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

(Please note that I skipped null checks and error handling for brevity's sake)

Comment: it still shows /null/ for id in the link :(

Comment: @Ivan Bumbak - the AsyncTask has a field mReviewData. Where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: that thing bothers me ... I have to put some string in .buildReviewUrl so if you put like ReviewData value or anything else except string I need to use String.valueOf() .... and in postExecute reviewData is automatically ArrayList ...

Comment: @Ivan Bumbak - well, you have to use a valid Url so you can fetch the reviews.Right now, mReviewData seems to stay null so String.valueOf(mReviewData) is "null". Why don't you use some hardcoded String as Url until you are able to make the rest work (fetch the reviews and show them in the app)? Later on you can make use of the fact that with your AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ReviewData> > you can pass the Url as entry in the String[] parameter for execute() and retrieve it from strings in doInBackground(String... strings)

Comment: I tried with ''0'', application works but doesn't show anything 'cause there is no movie with that ID ....  https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/0/reviews?api_key= ... that's the correct link, but instead of this ''0'' should go very long String id ... that's what I cannot get

Comment: @Ivan Bumbak - sorry but how should anyone here know the correct id for some movie review?  Obtaining a valid Url is not really a programming problem.

Comment: you get it probably from movieId ... API documentation and that stuff ...

Comment: @Ivan Bumbak - if someone published a documentation maybe they mentioned how to get (a list of all valid) id's from the server. But that's quite outside of  .the scope of the help you can get here. I tried to help you with the Android implementation problems, the rest is up to you.

Comment: I know, tnx, I'll do like bottom answer says :)

Answer (score 0):

1. In MovieDetails onCreate retrieve current movie ID like you do in displayMovieDetail.
2. Send that ID to ReviewAsyncTask (you'll need to modify constructor of ReviewAsyncTask)
3. Retrieve id in ReviewAsyncTask, save it as member variable, and then in doInBackground method send that id to buildReviewUrl as an argument.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some code with your suggestions to better showcase how to do it?